# how to toUpperCase() string+var

Tags: javascript

How is it possible to do this without making a var with the whole string first?

```
{'HDL_'+_parent.page+'_NUMBER'}.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
('HDL_'+_parent.page+'_NUMBER').toUpperCase();
```